# What are the differences btwn 'load' event vs readystatechange 'complete' event?

Tags: javascript

In my code, I'm waiting until the page is fully loaded before removing a loading spinner. "Fully loaded" in this instance includes css, images, etc, so `DOMContentLoaded` would happen too early.

I found both the `load` event and the `readystatechange` event checking for readyState "complete".

```
document.addEventListener('readystatechange'), (event) => {
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
        console.log("page fully loaded");
    }
}

document.addEventListener('load'), (event) => {
    console.log("page fully loaded");
}
```

The question is, are there any appreciable differences between these two? I'm looking to use the most widely supported option across browsers and devices. I've seen `readystatechange` referred to as an "alternative" for IE, but I think both events are firing across Firefox, Chrome, and Safari, when I try to test them.

Comment: I can not find a good dupe, this has been asked many times, but the answers are lacking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are nearly the same - the only difference is that the `readystatechange` event changes to `complete` *right before* the `load` event fires. See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) for `document.readyState`:

> **complete**
>
> The document and all sub-resources have finished loading. The state indicates that the `load` event is about to fire.

Also note that you should add the `load` listener to `window`, and that you need to pass the handler function to `addEventListener` rather than using the comma operator.

```js
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', (event) => {
  if (document.readyState === "complete") {
    console.log("readystatechange complete, adding timeout");
    setTimeout(() => console.log('timeout running'));
  }
});

window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  console.log("load handler running");
});
```

```html
<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-jE4axz9ZwU4/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACevoQPQhQkQ5T2LbDXKarOmW373pkQ0Ug/mo/photo.jpg?sz=32">
```

Notice how the timeout, despite being set with no delay in `readystatechange`, runs *after* the `load` event fires.

Comment: Whoops, that syntax was definitely a typo on my part when posting the question. Thank you for the snippet; that's very interesting.